# Why is "End of File" (EOF) the defacto delimeter for here documents?

Tags: python, ruby, file, shell, heredoc

From where did the phrase "End of File" arise for use with here documents?

```
something <<EOF
something else 1
something else 2
...
EOF
```

I assumed there's some history which might justify the nonintuitive limit string, and reading [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) didn't quite suffice: why has "file" still pervade programs while streams and blocks are more commonly use to build here documents?

Comment: Because `EOF` is "an actual thing" and people are used to it...?

Comment: You used `python` as one of your tags. Here documents don't need a delimiter in `python` since triple quotes are used, did you mean `perl`?

Comment: EOF is IMHO quite a good and intuitive marker. What makes you think it isn't ? What would you suggest instead ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes from Unix tradition, where [everything is a file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file). 'File' in this context doesn't mean 'diskfile', and doesn't necessarily imply any associated metadata - it means something quite a bit closer to what tends now to be called a 'stream'. At very most, 'file' is 'something accessed by a file descriptor'. In other words, the STDIN of the process you are spawning *is a file*, and the EOF of the heredoc marks the end of it.

Answer (score 3):

Because EOF standing for "end of file" has traditionally been used as the name of the marker or exception returned when reading a file in a program to indicate that the end of the file has been reached. This is a very old usage.

So when writing here documents and you need a token to mark the end of it (which should to be something unlikely to occur accidentally), "EOF" springs quite naturally to mind if you're used to using that phrase to refer to end-of-file markers. Since that's been used so often, it gets picked up even by people who *aren't* used to thinking of EOF that way already, because they see it used in examples when they're learning how to use here documents. And so the usage propagates.

Answer (score 0):

It’s just a convention. In shell scripts you can use pretty much anything, e.g.,

```
cat <<stackoverflow
something else 1
something else 2
...
stackoverflow
```

in `bash` does the same as if it said `EOF`.